# I need activate the last tab in tabpanel in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, tabpanel

I need activate the last tab in tabpanel in extjs.  I have a button that adds new tabs and I need to change the last added.

Comment: have you tried anything at all? try and share your code, it will help us help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the `length` of the `items` array and `setActiveTab` using that.

```
var last = tabPanel.items.length -1;
tabPanel.setActiveTab(last)
```

Here is [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/481) demonstrating a simple working example.

[Sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-cfg-items) is a huge help in figuring these things out.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, with this can resolve the problem.